# Authenticate phpBB using custom MS-SQL database

Tags: php, sql-server, phpbb

How can I let my users to log into a phpBB forum by entering their user credentials while these credentials are stored in a separate MS SQL database?

Comment: I mean I need to customize the authentication routine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a custom authentication plugin for phpbb. Since your requirement is authentication against a database, it should be pretty straight forward to re-use the existing plugin phpbb uses for authentication against it's own internal database.

Authentication plugins are located in `<install_dir>/includes/auth`

An authentication plugin must be named `auth_<your custom name>.php`

So in your case, create a copy of `auth_db.php` and call it e.g. `auth_mssql.php`

Authentication plugins are documented here: http://wiki.phpbb.com/Authentication_plugins