# Integrating PHPBB into Slim 3

Tags: php, phpbb3, slim-3

Has anyone managed to integrate PHPBB login system with a Slim 3 application?

I get the following error

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to
>   Slim\Collection::__construct() must be of the type array, object
>   given

When adding the code shown here:
[Full integrate phpbb into existing website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19241385/full-integrate-phpbb-into-existing-website)

Comment: just debug a bit and you will know what is causing problem. print_r() the argument that you are passing to this constructor...

Comment: That's why I'm asking...the argument being passed is exactly the same whether the integration code is there or not...Slim application works fine but when I add the code in the post linked to above it doesn't work anymore, but I'm not changing the argument being passed into the constructor